# ationDoes console.log() impact on performance in nodejs server in production mode?

Tags: node.js, performance, production-environment, console.log

When i test my Rest API using bench-rest npm package. At first i tested with console.log and without console.log and i realize that without console.log it is 2-3 times faster than with console.log. I just need to confirmation about this.

Comment: Of course logging is an expensive task.

Answer (score 0):

Surely any calls to `console` are expensive and thus should not be used in production mode. It's best to use any proper logger like [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) for example!